# How to avoid rebalance during ES cluster starts up

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 7.10.1. My cluster has 20 nodes.

I would start these 20 nodes one by one (the cluster already has data). During the startup, would rebalance happen because some have started up while some haven't?

I would if rebalance may happen, how could I avoid this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent rebalancing, you may run the following command, which is typically what is run before doing a [rolling upgrade](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rolling-upgrades.html) in order to prevent shards from being rebalanced to other nodes.

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "none"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @val. Yes, I could do so when the cluster is running,but how to avoid rebalance during cluster nodes start up one by one

Comment: You first need to start a master node, then you can run that command and as soon as you start data nodes, they will get the instructions to not rebalance their shards