# cluster.routing.allocation.enable: none seems not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I disable the shard allocation with following snippet:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "none"
  }
}
```

I double check `GET _cluster/settings'` and confirm it has been set with `none`.

But when I use the following snippet trying to move a shard between nodes. And the move succeeds,
looks the `"cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "none"` doesn't take effect?

```
POST /_cluster/reroute
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "move": {
        "index": "lib38",
        "shard": 0,
        "from_node": "node-1",
        "to_node": "node-3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually rerouting a shard will always take precedence over configuration.

`cluster.routing.allocation.enable` is only giving a hint to the cluster that **automatic** reallocation should not take place.

[In your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666074/how-to-avoid-rebalance-during-es-cluster-starts-up), you were concerned about automatic rebalancing, it seems.

Comment: Thanks @val for the great explanation. In the other question, I follow your answer and did a manual test, and saw the behavior in the question,now I understood, thanks!